# What is a Google Cloud Pub/Sub Snapshot?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I read all the Pub/Sub docs and saw no mention of Snapshots.

[image]

But when I read the docs for the Node.js Client Libraries, I find references to Snapshot objects:  https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/pubsub/0.11.0/pubsub/snapshot

Huh?

Answer (score 1):

It's an invite-only feature that seems to provide some sort of replayability functionality https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/pubsub/.

Comment: Thanks.  I only just today got a handle on the main/alpha/beta docs sections.